# How to print all elements of String array in Kotlin in a single line?

Tags: java, kotlin

This is my code

```
    fun main(args : Array<String>){
     var someList : Array<String> = arrayOf("United","Chelsea","Liverpool")

      //How do i print the elements using the print method in a single line?
    }
```

In java i would do something like this

`someList.forEach(java.lang.System.out::print);`

Comment: `println(arr.contentToString())`

Comment: `contentToString()` is great

Comment: `joinToString()` is even better. Look at @delitescere's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902332/15139).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[`Array`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html) has a [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) method as well which can take a lambda:

```
var someList : Array<String> = arrayOf("United","Chelsea","Liverpool")
someList.forEach { System.out.print(it) }
```

or a method reference:

```
var someList : Array<String> = arrayOf("United","Chelsea","Liverpool")
someList.forEach(System.out::print)
```

Comment: arr.forEach(::println)

Comment: System.out.println( someList.joinToString() )

Answer (score 53):

Idiomatically:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val someList = arrayOf("United", "Chelsea", "Liverpool")
  println(someList.joinToString(" "))
}
```

This makes use of type inference, an immutable value, and well-defined methods for doing well-defined tasks.

The `joinToString()` method also allows prefix and suffix to be included, a limit, and truncation indicator.

Answer (score 25):

You can achieve this using "contentToString" method:

```
var someList : Array<String> = arrayOf("United","Chelsea","Liverpool")
  println(someList.contentToString())

O/p:
[United, Chelsea, Liverpool]e
```

Answer (score 11):

I know three ways to do this:

```
(0 until someList.size).forEach { print(someList[it]) }
someList.forEach { print(it) }
someList.forEach(::print)
```

Hope you enjoyed it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){
    var someList : Array<String> = arrayOf("United","Chelsea","Liverpool")
    someList.forEach(System.out::print)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this, no need to use loop and iterate by yourself. [Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html)

```
println(someList.joinToString(","))
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @OkeUwechue `println(someList.joinToString())` is even better because the default parameter for the delimiter is `", "`

Answer (score 3):

You could

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){
  var someList : Array<String> = arrayOf("United","Chelsea","Liverpool")

  val sb = StringBuilder()
  for (element in someList) {
      sb.append(element).append(", ")
  }
  val c = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length-2)
  println(c)
}
```

gives

```
United, Chelsea, Liverpool
```

alternatively you can use

```
print(element)
```

in the for loop, or even easier use:

```
var d = someList.joinToString()
println(d)
```

Comment: joinToString seems what I was looking for, the equivalent to Arrays.toString()

Answer (score 0):

If it is solely for printing purpose then a good one liner is

```
 var someList : Array<String> = arrayOf("United","Chelsea","Liverpool")
 println(java.util.Arrays.toString(someList))
```